# divide sum by count using postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to divide sum by count but I get syntax error

```
    COALESCE(SUM(f_revenue),0)/COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN b_entry_das_tag = true THEN s_dedup_hash ` +
  `ELSE NULL END))::decimal
```

Comment: The `+` at the end looks very wrong. What exactly is the error message you get?

Comment: this query is inside a code

Comment: **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the **complete** query you are using and the **exact** error message you get. The `+` and the strange backticks certainly are very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question seems incomplete, but to do a partial count, it's usually easier to use the `filter()` operator:

```
COALESCE(SUM(f_revenue),0) 
/ 
(COUNT(DISTINCT s_dedup_hash) filter (where b_entry_das_tag = true))::decimal
```

Comment: @dcfds342423: well, unless you show us your **complete** code (and the **exact** error message), you won't get anything better.